# Will the particle reach other end?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, collision, brownian-motion

[image]

I place a container at rest in vaccum and filled it with air (STP conditions).
Suppose a moving particle(sphere of dia 2mm) is placed at one end of the container without disturbing anything, will the particle reach other end of the container?

I believe due to air friction(because of low reynols number) the particle may not reach(supposing that the velocity is small).
Assuming I place many particles in the same manner, one after the other, none of them should reach the other end and still the container will be at rest.

How close is this to reality.

Comment: It is not clear if you give an initial speed to the particle, and if so, what do you mean that you put it there without any disturbation?

Comment: It meant that placement of the particle does not move the container and do not cause any disturbance(like pressure diff) in the air.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the two animated gifs at the top of the [Brownian Motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_motion) page on Wikipedia.

Essentially your 2mm sphere will follow a random path due to the random collisions from the air molecules that given enough time will travel to most places in the container (assuming a starting velocity of 0).

If you give an initial velocity then its probably irrelevant what it is, the air friction will eventually slow it to 0 then you're back to your random path which will travel to all locations in the container (given enough time).  So either it will reach the other side due to its initial velocity or through random Brownian motion.

Air pressure, air temperature, density and elasticity of the sphere and size of the container will all effect the outcome but mostly changing them will just speed up or slow down the Brownian Motion (changing the size of the container will change how long it takes to reach the other side).

Note: If the temperature reaches absolute zero then there will be no motion of the air molecules and no Brownian Motion.

The only other effect is if there is gravity acting on the container or the container is accelerating (equivalent to being in a gravitational field).  In this case the gravity/acceleration will apply a force on the particle (downwards) which will most likely be stronger than the Brownian Motion.

Comment: Thank you. Suppose that the container is moving with constant velocity, it does not effect the behavior of particle. right?

Comment: If whoever (or whatever) places the sphere in the container is moving with the container then the entire frame of reference is equivalent to the stationary situation (so no it does not effect the particle).  If the container is moving independently then it simply gives an initial velocity to the particle which is discussed above.